# get difference result between ef(dbfirst) and Sql Query

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity

Before Start 
I Have View 'PageViewModSession' 
its code is

```
 SELECT        CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(14), VisitStartDateTime) +    ':00:00') AS DateValue, MAX(dbo.PageLogGroupByDateTimeFull(VisitStartDateTime))  AS PageLogCount, 
                     (CASE MAX(dbo.SessionGroupByDateTimeFull(VisitStartDateTime)) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(dbo.SessionGroupByDateTimeFull(VisitStartDateTime)) END) AS SessionLogCount, SiteInfoID
FROM            dbo.PageLog
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(14), VisitStartDateTime), SiteInfoID
```

and When select this views my result is 
[image: Sql Query Result.png]

and when select in ef with this syntaxt

```
 var obj = db.PageViewModSessions.AsQueryable();
```

result is
[image: Ef Result.png]

repeat row one in every row on result

i catch created Sql query query in profiler

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DateValue] AS [DateValue], 
[Extent1].[PageLogCount] AS [PageLogCount], 
[Extent1].[SessionLogCount] AS [SessionLogCount], 
[Extent1].[SiteInfoID] AS [SiteInfoID]
FROM (SELECT 
[PageViewModSession].[DateValue] AS [DateValue], 
[PageViewModSession].[PageLogCount] AS [PageLogCount], 
[PageViewModSession].[SessionLogCount] AS [SessionLogCount], 
[PageViewModSession].[SiteInfoID] AS [SiteInfoID]
FROM [dbo].[PageViewModSession] AS [PageViewModSession]) AS [Extent1]
```

and result is

```
2015-11-03 01:00:00.000        19        9        2
2015-11-03 02:00:00.000        19        4        2
2015-11-03 03:00:00.000        4        1        2
2015-11-03 11:00:00.000        7        5        2
2015-11-03 12:00:00.000        9        2        2
2015-11-04 01:00:00.000        1        1        2
2015-11-04 02:00:00.000        12        1        2
2015-11-04 03:00:00.000        5        1        2
2015-11-04 05:00:00.000        1        1        2
2015-11-04 06:00:00.000        4        1        2
2015-11-04 10:00:00.000        20        2        2
2015-11-04 11:00:00.000        19        4        2
2015-11-04 12:00:00.000        23        18        2
2015-11-05 02:00:00.000        1        1        2
2015-11-05 03:00:00.000        5        1        2
2015-11-05 04:00:00.000        25        2        2
2015-11-05 10:00:00.000        2        1        2
2015-11-05 11:00:00.000        3        1        2
```

why ?!!

and what have to do fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle This 
by Setting Two Key for model 
DateValueand SiteInfoId